# Managing Historical and Current Records with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, django, relational-database, django-orm

I want to keep track of each *User*'s current *balance* and *balance* history using the Django ORM.  I imagine 2 tables (*User* and *History*) with a one-to-many between *User* and *History* representing a user's entire history, and a one-to-one between *User* and *History* for easy access to the current *balance*:

```
History    
ID | User (FK to User) | Delta | Balance | Timestamp

User    
ID | Name | Employee | Year | Balance (FK to History)
```

1) Does this seem reasonable given that I'm using the Django ORM?  I think with raw SQL or another ORM, I could give history a start and stop date, then easily get the latest with `SELECT * FROM History WHERE user_id=[id] AND stop IS NULL;`.

2) Should History have a balance column?

3) Should User have a balance column (I could always compute the balance on the fly)?  If so, should it be a "cached" decimal value?  Or should it be a foreign key to the latest balance?

Answer (score 0):

A strictly normal approach would say that *neither* table should contain a balance column, but that users' balances should be calculated when required from the sum of all their history.  However, you may find that using such a schema would result in unacceptable performance—in which case cacheing the balance would be sensible:

- if you're mostly interested in the *current* balance, then there's little reason to cache balances in the `History` table (just cache the current balance in the `User` table alone);
- on the other hand, if you might be interested in arbitrary historical balances, then storing a historical balances in the `History` table would make sense (and then there'd be little point in also storing the current balance in the `User` table, since that could easily be discovered from the most recent `History` record).

But perhaps it's not worth worrying about cacheing right now?  Have in mind the mantra "*normalise until it hurts; denormalise until it works*" as well as Knuth's famous maxim "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*".